Excel (Business) connector in power automate can't see the excel files created by other users in SharePoint
I have trouble with the excel actions from the Excel (business) connector in power automate that is inside a flow I created. The action should run a script to protect the worksheets and then another action reads the sheet names.
The point is that when the creator of the excel file is me, the flow works normally without any problems. However, when someone else (in the same company) who have access to the SharePoint library create it, the actions throw an HTTP 404 error: Item not found, even if that user have full control permissions.

Please help me resolving this issue.

Is Check in/Check out enabled in this library?

@AmyJiang_MSFT No it is not. Thank you for your response though.

do you (or the user, who triggers the flow) access those files which are created by other users? It seems, this causes the problem, your flow can't see the file.

I was enabled the content approval and only the file creator can see the draft files. Now when I make the drafts visible for everyone the excel connector is working fine. Thank you so much.
